# when using event.target it works on website but on code has error

Tags: javascript, typescript, events

With javascript I check if the user clicks inside 2 divs with event.target, it works but in code it gives this error message:

Argument of type 'EventTarget | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Node | null'.
  Type 'EventTarget' is missing the following properties from type 'Node': baseURI, childNodes, firstChild, isConnected, and 44 more.Vetur(2345)

```
cogsClose() {
    if (
      !document.querySelector(".cogs-window")!.contains(event.target)! &&
      !document.querySelector(".fa-cogs")!.contains(event.target)
    ) {
      document.getElementById("cogs-user")!.classList.add("cogs-hide");
      document.getElementById("cogs-tabs")!.classList.add("cogs-hide");
    }
  }
```

The error shows on both of the event.target.

Comment: Why put '!' anywhere ???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's check what lib.dom.d.ts says abut that. So the contains functions signature looks like this:

```js
contains(other: Node | null): boolean;
```

and typing for mouseEvent's property target is

```js
readonly target: EventTarget | null;
```

EventTarget is not compatible type with Node. This is because target don't have to be always Node type as is mention in [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget).
But if you are sure about the typing then u can just cast that right to Node or HTMLElement or something like that.

```js
.contains(<Node>(event!.target))
```

But be careful about that.. Types are here to protect us so signature looks like this for some reason. Same for using ! everywhere..

Answer (score 3):

It worked for me

```
.contains(event.target as Node)
```